# Как включить автообновление базы данных mysql через библиотеку threading

Tags: python

```
def connect():
    try:
        # тут куда-то я так понимаю надо вставить эту библиотеку, каким образом?
        connection = pymysql.connect(
        host = '....',
        user ='...',
        password = '..',
        database = '...',
        cursorclass = pymysql.cursors.DictCursor
        )
```

Comment: Какое автообновление, зачем threading? Ничего не понятно

Comment: А можно по подробнее, что надо сделать? Как должно работать и что хотите получить в итоге?